# Zend DB Framework3 SQL Server Select Limit

Tags: sql-server, php-7, zend-db, zend-framework3

I am using Zend DB SQL Abstraction to query several different databases. On most of these I can add a limit to the select statement but it is not working on SQL Server.

```
$limit = 10; // this is actually coming in from the calling code
$options = array(
  'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
  'hostname' => '<hostname>',
  'database' => '<schema>',
  'username' => '<username>',
  'password' => '<password>',
);
$db = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($options);
$sql = new Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($db);
$select = $sql->select(<table name>);
$select->columns([<columns>]);
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where(<zero or more where statements>);
$select->where($where);
if($limit > 0) {
  $select->limit($limit);
}
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

When I run this, I get an error

> Statement could not be executed (42000 - 102 - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.)

When I output `$select->getSqlString($db->getPlatform())` I get

> SELECT [field names] FROM [table name] WHERE [where clauses] LIMIT 10

when I am expecting

> SELECT TOP 10 [field names] FROM [table name] WHERE [where clauses]

What am I missing on this?

Comment: While this may not be an answer to your question. I'd highly recommend turning your SQL statement into some sort of stored procedure with defined parameters or you may run into injection troubles. Edit: actually if you turned that into a stored proc you'd also have a much easier time setting that limit as well.

Comment: I'm accessing the database for an external system. I only have read privileges to it, so creating a stored procedure is not an option.

Comment: See `quantifier` function like second answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811334/zend-framework-query-top

Comment: make sure $limit be an integer, not a string.